# How long live an OAuth access token after an refresh of the token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

If I refresh an OAuth2 access token, is the current (old) token valid or invalid? Will the old access token valid until it receive its expired time?

In my applications there are multiple threads that use the same access token parallel. If the access token is going to its live end, for example there is only a minute until it expired, then one thread request a new access token with an refresh token.

Does I need a read lock on the access token to prevent a refresh on using the access token?

Comment: Are you using signed access tokens like JWT?

Comment: I does not understand what you means. The access token can be a JWT token or not. This depends on the provider implementation. Practical the token is black box that is used 1:1 for Bearer authentication. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1